# Converting Promise information to observable

Tags: angular

I followed the Tour of Hero guide but have decided Observables are better than promises but I am having trouble implementing them.

Here is my recipe service:

```
import { of } from 'rxjs/Observable/of';
...
  getRecipes(): Observable<Recipe[]> {
    return of(RECIPES);
  }

  getRecipe(id: number): Observable<Recipe> {
    return this.getRecipes()
      .subscribe(recipes => recipes.find(recipe => recipe.ID === id));
  }
```

I am not sure how to get a specific observable item from an obvserable array like I did with promises on the tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use map for this case, your implementation can be following

```
 getRecipe(id: number): Observable<Recipe> {
     return this.getRecipes()
          .map(recipies => recipies.find(x => x.id === id));
  }
```

Comment: What is 'x' and what do I actually use there

Comment: my bad it should be x => x.id === id, there was mistake correct the answer now

Comment: Thanks, so when we call 'x' we are calling it from its parent so it can be named anything? also how do I then use this observable, I am trying to do 'ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.paramMap
      .switchMap((params: ParamMap) => this.recipeService.getRecipe(+params.get('id')))
      .subscribe(recipe => this.recipe = recipe);

  }' but it doesnt load the item in

Comment: You need to write   import 'rxjs/add/operator/map' in your service

Comment: import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'

Comment: Thanks so much, but why did it allow me to use the map function (wasnt red or anything) without it being imported?  thanks so much for all the help!

Comment: Beacause you might have imported entire rxjs.